# Possible to select individual values using SHOW STATUS in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to write a query that will return only the value of a variable returned by MySQL's SHOW STATUS? Ideally I want something like:

```
SELECT `Value` FROM (SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Com_delete')
```

or something similar.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.1 or above, you should be able to get that data from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` like this for global status:

```
select VARIABLE_VALUE 
from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Com_delete';
```

Or if you want the session status instead:

```
select VARIABLE_VALUE 
from information_schema.SESSION_STATUS 
where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Com_delete';
```

The default for `SHOW STATUS` is `SESSION` status, so the latter query would work as a replacement for that.

Comment: hmm... unfortunately i'm not. i'm using 5.0.45

Comment: Too bad. You can do something like this to get the value on the command line: `mysql -sse "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Com_delete';" | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: you are life saver. This works great with JMeter DBMon plugin to monitor MySQL performance.

Comment: Isn't the first example the global status, and the 2nd the session one?

Comment: Note that `information_schema` is deprecated, and using `performance_schema` is the solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744667/2716218

Answer (score 7):

Complementing Ike Walker answer, INFORMATION_SCHEMA is deprecated on MySQL 5.7.6, as the Performance Schema tables are intended to replace the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables.

So, by querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA you may get an error like this:

> The 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_STATUS' feature is disabled; see the
>   documentation for 'show_compatibility_56'

According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-variable-table-migration.html), you can set `show_compatibility_56` to `ON` to enable backwards compatibility and keep using 5.6 syntax, or enable the PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA and query the new tables:

```
performance_schema.global_variables
performance_schema.session_variables

performance_schema.global_status
performance_schema.session_status
```